# What is the best way to build Flutter with plugins that support Androidx?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, androidx, flutter-dependencies

The following link lists the minimum plugin versions that are pre-Androidx

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Androidx requires minimum Android 9.0 (API level 28). This may not be supported across all android devices. What is the best way to build Flutter apps in such cases ? Maintaining two code bases one with and one without Androidx seems to be painful.

Comment: AndroidX is a  package re-versioned support libraries. They have backward compatibility support to work on lower API devices.

Comment: @JarinRocks said the truth but if you want to provide support for apps that hasn't migrated to androidX you can start developing your plugin with deprecated SupportLibrary release this version and then migrate your plugin to AndroidX and release this new version with this breaking change documented.